# Golang - Why does this race condition occur？

Tags: concurrency, go, race-condition, goroutine

```
package main
import "fmt"

var quit chan int
var glo int

func test() {
    fmt.Println(glo)
}

func main() {
    glo = 0
    n := 10000
    quit = make(chan int, n)
    go test()
    for {
        quit <- 1
        glo++
    }
}
```

**Situation:**

The above program outputs 10000. But when I assign a bigger number to *n* (e.g. `n := 1000000`), the output will be a random number *less than n*.

I haven't called `runtime.GOMAXPROCS()`, so these two goroutines can't run in parallel. Executing `go run -race` to detect race conditions, ends up *without* any warnings.

**Question:**

Why does this race condition occur?

Comment: Why do you think this code doesn't have a race condition? The goroutine runs concurrently with the for loop and there's no synchronization performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no synchronisation between the `main` and `test` goroutines, you don't know at what point the `fmt.Println` call in `test` will happen.

When running with `GOMAXPROCS = 1`, the answer will essentially depend on when the scheduler decides to stop executing `main` and switch to `test`.  The send operation within the loop is one point where the scheduler can switch over to another goroutine, so with enough iterations of the loop you'd expect `test` to get a chance to execute at some point.  It isn't necessarily going to switch at the same iteration every run leading to the variation in results.

As for catching this with the race detector, it successfully catches the problem for me:

```
$ go run -race test.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read by goroutine 5:
  main.test()
      /../test.go:8 +0x6e

Previous write by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /.../test.go:18 +0xfe

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /.../test.go:15 +0x8f
==================
...
```

Comment: Thank you! But my race detector really can't catch the problem, I don't know why. My go version is 1.4.2.

Comment: The system I tested this on had Go 1.3.3 installed (Ubuntu 15.04 on amd64).  I haven't tested it on 1.4.2 myself.

Comment: It seems that when a deadlock occurs the race detector can't catch the problem. I manage to prevent deadlock and the race detector catch the problem successfully.

Comment: You've definitely got a deadlock, with your `main` gouroutine filling up a channel that isn't being drained.  I elided that from the output in my answer because that isn't from the race detector, and I assumed you'd already seen that bit.

Comment: The [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector#TOC_5.) does not issue false positives, but it can have false negatives (i.e. a run without any `-race` reports does not mean there are no races).